# How coloring data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

I have data frame of the following type

```
> df
              V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1   10.603.3.100  2  1  5  1
2   10.603.3.101  3  2  4  5
3   10.603.3.102  1  3  3  2
4   10.603.1.103  4  4  3  3
5   10.603.3.104  5  5  1  4
```

And the task is to colorize values by any palette by columns V2, V3, V4, V5. But unfortunately I have absolutely no ideas how to do it. The forum found answers to the question of coloring in two colors.

Something similar

[image]

Comment: Are these RGBA values ? Or are you trying to assign a distinct color to every set of V2 to V5 column ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper yes, I meant exactly this

Comment: From your example it seems it's actually neither of my proposals. Maybe use package `ggplot2` with `geom_tile` and `geom_text`. But really your question is super unclear, you can't color a "value". And at this point I'm still not sure if you want to plot it as an image, or as an html table or maybe directly in Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly then you may use `library(DT)` to colorise your columns like below:

`?datatable` from DT package:

> This function creates an HTML widget to display rectangular data (a
>   matrix or data frame) using the JavaScript library DataTables.

```
df <- head(iris, 10)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

datatable(df, rownames = FALSE) %>%
  formatStyle(columns = "Sepal.Length", 
              backgroundColor = "yellow") %>%
  formatStyle(columns = "Sepal.Width", 
              backgroundColor = "blue") %>%
  formatStyle(columns = "Petal.Width", 
              backgroundColor = "green")
```

[image]

**New EDIT after OP added Picture**:

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(matrix(round(rnorm(50), 3), 10), sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)))


breaks <- quantile(df, probs = seq(.05, .95, .05), na.rm = TRUE)
colors <- round(seq(255, 40, length.out = length(breaks) + 1), 0) %>% 
  {paste0("rgb(255,", ., ",", ., ")")}
datatable(df) %>% formatStyle(names(df), backgroundColor = styleInterval(breaks, colors))
```

[image]

You can check more from [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html):

The above example is taken straight from the above place, Please note that if you want to change the color you have to change the "colors" object with different value of rgb, for example if you change the above string with
this:

```
colors <- round(seq(255, 40, length.out = length(breaks) + 1), 0) %>% 
  {paste0("rgb(", ., ",255,", ., ")")}
```

You will get parrot green flavour instead of red.

Comment: not quite that. you can see an example of a coloring in the description. I added an image

Comment: @Dmitry are you talking about conditional formatting, It is not clear earlier from your question, I will update my answer, wait for some moment

Answer (score 1):

How about a heatmap?

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(circlize)

set.seed(123)

mat = cbind(rbind(matrix(rnorm(16, -1), 4), matrix(rnorm(32, 1), 8)),
            rbind(matrix(rnorm(24, 1), 4), matrix(rnorm(48, -1), 8)))

# permute the rows and columns
mat = mat[sample(nrow(mat), nrow(mat)), sample(ncol(mat), ncol(mat))]

rownames(mat) = paste0("R", 1:12)
colnames(mat) = paste0("C", 1:10)
```

Plot the heatmap with default settings. The default style of the heatmap is quite the same as those generated by other similar heatmap functions.

```
Heatmap(mat)
```

[image]

https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/ComplexHeatmap/inst/doc/s2.single_heatmap.html