# R: Convert data.frame to color matrix using ggplot2?

Tags: r, matrix, ggplot2, colors

Does anyone know how to use ggplot2 to convert a data frame in R with continous values into a pretty figure. This would be similar to the answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47716586/how-coloring-data-frame-in-r) but with ggplot2.

Is this possible?

New to R and ggplot2 so thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: You might be able to do something similar to this: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-quick-correlation-matrix-heatmap-r-software-and-data-visualization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using the `mtcars` data (scaled to give comparable values, so the numbers don't mean much).

The key things are the use of `gather` to tidy the data, `geom_tile` filled by value, and `geom_text` for the labels. Everything else is just manipulation of that particular data frame.

You could also just use one of the `scale_fill_gradient` geoms.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)

mtcars %>% 
  scale() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "make") %>% 
  gather(var, val, -make) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(var, make)) + 
    geom_tile(aes(fill = val)) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = round(val, 2)), 
              size = 3) + 
    coord_fixed() + 
    scale_fill_viridis() + 
    guides(fill = FALSE)
```

[image]

Or using:

```
+ scale_fill_gradient2(midpoint = 1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks nielfws! This is exactly what I was looking for.