# Add color to the dataframe

Tags: r

Is there a way to add a color the cells in the dataframe. For example

```
df
ColA   ColB
12     Pass
14     fail
12     Pass
```

Expected output (ColB needs to be colored. If Pass, then green then red)

[image]

Comment: This might help use `library(DT)`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47716586/how-coloring-data-frame-in-r/47717044#47717044 and https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with the `gt` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)
library(scales)
df %>% 
  gt() %>%
  data_color(columns = 2, 
             colors = col_factor(palette = c("green","red"),
                                  domain = c("Pass","fail")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But the ````class(df)```` becomes ````[1] "gt_tbl" "list" ````. Can not keep it a dataframe?

Comment: No, `data.frame`s in R are not set up to include information about color of individual elements. You'll have to use a different class of object.

Answer (score 1):

An option with `datatable`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble::tribble(
        ~ColA,  ~ColB,
          12L, "Pass",
          14L, "fail",
          12L, "Pass"
        )

library(DT)
datatable(df) %>% formatStyle(
  'ColB',
  backgroundColor = styleEqual(c("Pass", "fail"), c('red', 'green'))
)
```

[image]